# Best solution for returning results from a generic Typescript service

Tags: typescript, angular-2+

I am beginning to develop a common data service that can be used by other services. Specifically, this service will be injected into a generic abstract application service. I am trying to figure out the best way to return the results from these services.

I chose to setup a common wrapper for the HTTP service to consume a custom IResult from my API application. It allows for system messages (error, warnings, successes), typical post/get commands, and so it can be used throughout the application with ease. I am using [blockUI](https://github.com/kuuurt13/ng-block-ui) to show a loading indicator

The common data service:

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {
    private reqData = {};
    private url: string;
    @BlockUI() blockUI: NgBlockUI;
    constructor(private http: Http) {

    }

    post(url: string, data: any, blockUi: boolean, blockUiMessage?: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<IResult> {
        // some logic

        return this.http.post(url, data, options)
            .map((response: Response) => {
                if (blockUi)
                    this.blockUI.stop();

                var result = <IResult>response.json();
                if(result.Message && result.Message.DisplayMessage)
                    this.showMessage(result.Message);
                return result;
            })
            .catch((error: Response) => {
                if (blockUi)
                    this.blockUI.stop();
                console.log(error);
               return Observable.throw('Server error');

            });

    }


    public get(url: string, blockUi: boolean, blockUiMessage?: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs):
        Observable<IResult> {

        if (!blockUiMessage || blockUiMessage.length <= 0)
            blockUiMessage = 'Please Wait...';

        if (blockUi)
            this.blockUI.start(blockUiMessage);

        return this.http.get(url, options)
            .map((response: Response) => {
                if (blockUi)
                    this.blockUI.stop();
                var result = <IResult>response.json();
                if (result.Message && result.Message.DisplayMessage)
                    this.showMessage(result.Message);
                return result;


            })
            .catch((error: Response) => {
                if (blockUi)
                    this.blockUI.stop();
                console.log(error);
                var result = <IResult>error.json();
                this.showMessage(result.Message);
                return Observable.throw(error.json() || 'Server error');

            });
    }

    public showMessage(message: any) {

        ...code to display growl type messages
    }
}
```

My back-end API exposes commands for `GetById<T>`, `GetAll<IEnumberable<T>>`, etc. I then wanted to create an abstract; generic base service class that would be used by specific application types. It also requires the user be authenticated. I add an Authorization header for each request in the constructor to ensure this.

The `BaseClientDto` is a simple class to expose properties required by the `BaseHttpAuthorizationService`. This is best illustrated by the `getById` method.

```
@Injectable()
export abstract class BaseHttpAuthorizationService<T extends BaseClientDto> {

    public header: Headers;
    public model: BehaviorSubject<T>;
    public httpResult: any;
    public modelCollection: T[];

    constructor(public authService: AuthenticationService, public dataService: DataService) {

        this.model = BehaviorSubject.create();
        if (this.authService.isAuthenticated())
            this.header = new Headers({ 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.authService.getUserFromLocalStorage().token });

    }


    public getDataService(): DataService {
        return this.dataService;
    }

    public getById(dto: T) {

        var url = this.buildUri(dto.constructor.name) + dto.Id;
        this.dataService.get(url, true, 'Loading...', new RequestOptions({ headers: this.header }))
            .subscribe(result => {
                console.log(result.Model);
                this.model.next(<T>result.Model);
            });

    }


    public getAll(dto: T) {

        var url = this.buildUri(dto.constructor.name);
        this.dataService.post(url, dto, true, 'Loading...', new RequestOptions({ headers: this.header }))
            .subscribe(result => {
                this.modelCollection = <T[]>result.model;
            });

    }



    public deleteHard(dto: T) {
        var url = this.buildUri(dto.constructor.name) + 'delete/hard/' + dto.Id;
        this.dataService.post(url, dto, true, 'Loading...', new RequestOptions({ headers: this.header }))
            .subscribe(result => {
                this.httpResult = result;
            });

    }

    public buildUri(typeName: string) {

        if (typeName.toLowerCase().indexOf("dto") !== -1)
            typeName = typeName.toLowerCase().replace('dto', '');
       return globalContansts.ApiUrl typeName + "/";
    }
}
```

I'd like my methods to return whatever T is, rather than a type of observable. s you can see in the generic base class, the `model` property is setup as a `BehaviorSubject<T>`. I did this so my implemented classes could subscribe to the property and get the value, but this seems clunky to me. I end up having to do something like this in the implemented class to get the result:

```
export class SomeObjectService extends BaseHttpAuthorizationService<SomeObject>{

someObject = SomeObject;

   constructor(){
        this.someObject = Observable.create((observer: any) => {
            this.implmentedService.model.asObservable()
                   .subscribe((result: SomeObject) => {
                       observer.next(result);

                   });
           });
   }
}
```

I am sure there is a better way to set this up than how I currently have it.

Answer (score 2):

First, you could switch over to HttpClient (from '@angular/common/http') instead of Http in your DataService. Then, you could use (import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';) return a Promise instead of an Observable:

```
return this.http.get(url, options)
        .toPromise()
        .then((response: Response) => {
            if (blockUi)
                this.blockUI.stop();
            var result = <IResult>response;
            if (result.Message && result.Message.DisplayMessage)
                this.showMessage(result.Message);
            return result;
        })
        .catch(this.handleError);
```

Now, in your implementation, you could do this:

```
    public getById(dto: T) {

    var url = this.buildUri(dto.constructor.name) + dto.Id;
    this.dataService.get(url, true, 'Loading...', new RequestOptions({ headers: this.header }))
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result);
            this.SomeObject = result; // need a deserializer / loader to not kill other methods of SomeObject if that class is more than a pure DTO
        });
    }
```

However, I'm having a similar problem. I'm losing the properties / methods of my returned Type because the object is assigned to the returned JSON string. I'm working on a de-serialization method to preserve the object.

Comment: My only concern is not having the ability to cancel the request or inspect requests for duplicates. I need to ask myself how often I really need to perform those options.